# Writing common logic to get table sort and pagination preferences from API and display data accordingly angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I am trying to write a custom logic on material design [table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). 
Where I want to save the preferences like [matSortActive](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#MatSort), [matSortDirection](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#MatSort) and when next time user comes to the same component he is able to view the table as per his saved preferences. 
For that I have saved the preferences in local storage then retrieving it and displaying the data.

I want to write a custom directive which can read the localstorage and apply these settings directly. No need to write same code in component or any service for reusability.

My directive is

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../services/local-storage.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[savePrefrences]'
})
export class SavePrefrencesDirective implements OnInit{
  @Input() set savePrefrences(prefrencesEvent) {
    prefrencesEvent.subscribe((prefr) => {
    if(!prefr || !prefr.component ||
      !prefr.event){
        return;
    }
    let savePref = {
      event: prefr.event,
      pageSize: prefr.pageSize,
      filter: prefr.filters
    }
    let pref = {};
    let currentPref = this.getPreferencesObject();
    if(currentPref){ //[prefr.component]
      let prefParse = currentPref;
      if(prefParse[prefr.component]){
        prefParse[prefr.component] = savePref;
        pref = prefParse;
      }
    } else {
      pref[prefr.component] = savePref;
    }
    this.setPreferencesObject(pref);
    });
  }
  getPreferencesObject() {
    let currentPref = this.localStorageService.getKey('preferences');
    if(currentPref){
      return JSON.parse(currentPref);
    }
    return null;
  }
  setPreferencesObject(prefObject: any){
    console.log('setting prefrences object' + prefObject);
    this.localStorageService.setKey('preferences', JSON.stringify(prefObject));
  }
}
```

Corresponding html code is

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [savePrefrences]='sortEvent' matSortDirection='{{sortPref.direction}}' matSortActive='{{sortPref.name}}' (matSortChange)="sortChange($event)"></mat-table>
```

Here savePrefrences is directive which takes sortEvent as event emitter which saves all preferences as an object. As shown in code.

Currently I am providing **matSortDirection** and **matSortActive** values from component.